# Why do I get the same date with the following formatDate function?

Tags: javascript

I have dates like this:

```
2016-05-12T09:49:01.547Z
2016-05-09T11:18:57.006Z
2016-05-12T09:49:01.547Z
```

I'm using this function:

```
function formatDate (date) {
  const dateObj = new Date()
  const y = dateObj.getFullYear()
  const m = dateObj.getMonth(date) + 1
  const d = dateObj.getDate(date)
  return y + '/' + m + '/' + d
}
```

In this way:

function buildingTemplate (building) {
  date: formatDate(building.updatedAt)
    isDirty: false
  }
}

To produce this:

```
2016/5/12
2016/5/12
2016/5/12
```

But as you can see the date is always today, instead of the dates that I want to convert to that format to.

Why is this?

Comment: you aren't using the `date` parameter.

Comment: You need to remove `const dateObj = new Date()` and instead use the parameter passed to the function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change the function as bellow

```js
function formatDate(date) {
  const dateObj = new Date(date);
  const y = dateObj.getFullYear();
  const m = dateObj.getMonth() + 1;
  const d = dateObj.getDate();
  return y + '/' + m + '/' + d;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You totally ignore the passed `date` argument. Put it into the `Date` object constructor:

```
const dateObj = new Date(date);
```

If you create `new Date(date)` object without any argument, you will get current date - that's why you got tripple `2016/5/12`.

Answer (score 1):

You have used `date` in wrong way. Your function should looks like:

```
function formatDate (date) {
    const dateObj = new Date(date)
    const y = dateObj.getFullYear()
    const m = dateObj.getMonth() + 1
    const d = dateObj.getDate()
    return y + '/' + m + '/' + d
}
```

Also, i want to suggest you http://momentjs.com/ library, which is standard librabry for work with dates. It has big API and small size.